# Как проверить строку на один из вариантов правильно?

Tags: java, android

Есть входное число, нужно его проверить.
К примеру ввел я 1 проверить в диапазоне от 1 до 31.
Могу через цикл, но может есть какой-то красивый способ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте условный оператор if:

```
    int number = 1;
    if (number >= 1 && number <= 31) System.out.println(true);
```